# Rails - method not saving check_box_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, api, themoviedb-api

I am continuing my project on the tmdb api and in the process of saving the result of my query. I created the method `add_tmdb` to handle this. As for my view, this is what I have:

```
= form_tag :action => 'add_tmdb' do
  ... stuff here
   %td= check_box_tag "movie_id[]", movie.id
 = submit_tag 'Add selected movie'
```

My `controller` is below:

```
def add_tmdb
    movie = {params[:movie_id] => :id}
    Movie.create!(movie)
    flash[:notice] = "#{params[:movie_id]} was successfully created."
    redirect_to movies_path
end
```

When I submit the record, I get an active record error. This is what I receive:

```
unknown attribute '["7555"]' for Movie.
```

Where do I need to make the change?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The value of `params[:movie_id]` is a single element array. You're using that value as the key of your hash:

```
{params[:movie_id] => :id}
```

If you want to specify a key of `:id` with a value of `params[:movei_id]`, then your hash is backwards. You need

```
{ id: params[:movie_id] }
```

Comment: Ah thank you @meagar. How do I proceed in adding the title, rating and release date of the movie? I have a method that permits the following:

    def tmdb_params
         params.require(:search_terms).permit(:id, :title, :release_date, :rating)         end

Answer (score 0):

You may be accessing an `API`, but I still think your code needs to be structured better:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :movies

#app/controllers/movies_controller.rb
class MoviesController < ApplicationController
   def new
      @movie = Movie.new
      @movies = [[get data for Movies -- from API?]]
   end

   def create
      @movie = Movie.new movie_params
      @movie.save
   end

   private

   def movie_params
      params.require(:movie).permit(:id, :title, :rating, :release_date)
   end
end
```

Then your form is as follows:

```
#app/views/movies/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @movie do |f| %>
   <%= f.text_field :title %>
   <%= f.text_field :rating %>
   <%= f.collection_check_boxes :id, @movies, :id, :name %>
   <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Currently, your flow is not conventional; it doesn't build and object properly and doesn't protect against [mass assignment](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters#strong-parameters).

Everything in Rails/Ruby is [*object orientated*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming), meaning that when you "create" a new record, you're building a new *object*. Might sound trivial, but it's the core of the entire Rails framework.

Your comment of *"How do I proceed in adding the title, rating and release date of the movie"* demonstrates the ramifications of not adhering to it.

In short, you need `new`,`create` actions, both referencing a new `Movie` object, which you can then populate the with the params sent from your views.

---

**API**

The only exception you should make to the above would be if your flow is dependent on `API` callbacks, like through a billing system or something.

If you want to retain your current flow (IE call `add_tmdb`), you'll want to make sure you're populating the *attributes* of your `Movie` object as follows:

```
#app/controllers/movies_controller.rb
class MoviesController < ApplicationController
   def add_tmdb
      @movie = Movie.new
      @movie.id = params[:movie_id]
      @movie.save

      #or....
      @movie = Movie.new({id: params[:movie_id]})
      @movie.save
   end
end
```

Comment: Thank you @Rich. I needed that nudge. With a little bit of research and further reads, I will be able to fully grasp it. My controller has the new and create methods. What I am struggling with is after the fact that I pass the tmdb result to a view, I need to grab them and save the attributes. I think your API callback you mentioned below is something I need to work on.

Comment: Good to hear you got through it in your head; did you work out the API stuff or not?

Comment: My thick head you mean? No not yet. I am still figuring out the appropriate calls.

Comment: Tmdb gem. I'll share my hold up in a bit.

Comment: So I continued with using the `add_tmdb` method. I will have to revisit the `new` and `create` method. @Rich, I actually posted a new question. Here is the [link] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33331649/rails-continuing-to-work-on-check-box-tag?noredirect=1#comment54460252_33331649